# z.load in apache zeppelin results in error

Tags: apache-zeppelin

[image]i'm trying z.load in apache zeppelin as following:

```
%dep
z.load("/zeppelin-0.5.6-incubating-bin-all/lplibs/hive/csv-serde-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar")
```

I get an `ERROR` and it says (not sure this is the error):

```
Must be used before SparkInterpreter (%spark) initialized
Hint: put this paragraph before any Spark code and restart Zeppelin/Interpreter
```

this zeppelin section is the **first** i have in my notebook so i'm not sure what its complaining about..

Answer (score 1):

Right now I can't check your problem, but you should restart interpreter (pushing restart button) before loading dependency jar file.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a chance that Sparkcontext has already been started by other notebook.

So as Kangrok mentioned, just restart Spark interpreter.

But apart from that, why don't you use the latest zeppelin, in which you don't need to use %dep to load your dependencies. Instead it can load from Interpreter screen.

More details can be found here https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.6.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT/manual/dependencymanagement.html